# How to loop within a Linq to XML statement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

How how can I do this:

```
XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("SqlInstall",
            new XElement("Catalogs",
                    new XElement("Install"),
                    foreach (var item in packagedProduct.Installs)
                    {
                            new XElement("File ")..
                    }

                    ))));
```

It complains about the foreach loop within the Linq statement with "invalid expression term foreach"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The foreach loop should be rewritten like that:

```
packagedProduct.Installs.Select( item => new XElement("File ").. );
```